# ReWrite rule for long URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having Rewrite rule ad follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/$2/$3  [L]
```

if the URL comes like, `http://www.example.com/manage/ne/new?query=123 means` , i cont get the value of 'query' passed in url using "$_GET" in php .

it redirect like  `http://www.example.com/index.php?rt=manage/ne/new

but my need is `http://www.example.com/index.php?rt=manage/ne/new&query=123`

can any one help me to fix this issues regarding Htacces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `QSA` flags in bottom 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1/$2/$3  [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.